# How does node stacking work in a trie in C?

Tags: c, struct, trie

I have been struggling to clearly understand how stacking nodes into the root node works in a [trie.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)
More specifically when new nodes are being created and the somehow added to the root node.

So far what I have been able to comprehend is that there is a struct and a root node:

(assuming this trie is handling words)

```
typedef struct trieNode
{
    bool isEndOfWord;
    struct trieNode *children[26];
} trieNode;

// for now let's say all these nodes are initialized for the sake of simplicity
trieNode *root;
```

If I were to add another node to the root would it be implemented like this?

```
// scan the word character by character (assume word is something like "dog")
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
{
    // if character does not exist, create a new node and point root to it
    if(root->children[word[i] - 'a'] == NULL)
    {
            trieNode *newNode = makeNewNode(); // function to quickly initialize a node (not important for this question though)
            if(i == strlen(word) - 1) newNode->endOfWord = true;
            else root->endOfWord = false;

            // this is where I think I am making my logic error
            root->children[word[i] - 'a'] = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        // move to a new node
        root = root->children[word[i] - 'a'];
    }
}
```

Are these two statements
`root->children[word[i] - 'a'] = newNode;`, and `root = root->children[word[i] - 'a'];` used correctly? And if not, how could I make them do what they were intended for?

Comment: `word[i] - 'a'` gives you the zero-based letter index, provided that the word contains only lower-case letters. If you have upper-case letters or punctuation in the word, the index will be invalid. It might be a good idea to calculate that index once at the beginning and then check it for validity.

Comment: When you create a new node, you must advance `root` to the newly created node. You can achieve this by making `root = root->children[word[i] - 'a'];` a statement that is always executed after your `if` clause. You don't need an `else` here: If you have a valid next node, okay. If not, create it and you are also okay. Then advance to that node, that is now guanateed to exist.